# Why my appendix is part of last chapter?

Tags: table-of-contents, pdf, appendices, appendix

My appendix results in chapter 3. The printed pdf says §3.1SecThreeDotOne on intestation.
The \ref line in sec 2.2 prints 3.1. If I write \chapter{Appendix} without *, in ToC it prints Chapter 4: Appendix. Why? 
 Thanks

```
\begin{document}  
\tableofcontents  

\chapter*{Intro}  
        bla bla bla

\chapter{Cap 1}  
    \section{Sec 1.1}
        bla bla bla
    \section{Sec 1.2}
        bla bla bla
        \subsection{SubSec 1.2.1}
            bla bla bla

\chapter{Cap 2}
    \section{Sec 2.1}
        bla bla bla
    \section{Sec 2.2}
        \ref{sec:arduino}

\chapter{Cap 3}
    \section{SecThreeDotOne}
        bla bla bla

\chapter*{Outro}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Outro}
    bla bla bla

\chapter*{Appendix}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Appendix: Arduino}
\label{sec:arduino}
    bla bla bla

\end{document}
```

Comment: `*` is a unenumerated version of without star environment. similarly `\section*` is a section without number. So writing just `appendix` inside the `\chapter{}` is not that means that it is an appendix!

Comment: Also note that If an object does not have a name, how do you call it? here the object you have labeled it `\label{sec:arduino}` has no name because it is inside of an stared environment.

Answer (score 1):

A `\chapter*` command produces an unnumbered chapter, does not enter it into the ToC and does not increment the chapter number. Try this version of your (incomplete) MWE.

```
% appendixprob.tex  SE 564548
\documentclass{book} % PW added
\begin{document}  
\tableofcontents  

\chapter*{Intro}  
        bla bla bla

\chapter{Cap 1}  
    \section{Sec 1.1}
        bla bla bla
    \section{Sec 1.2}
        bla bla bla
        \subsection{SubSec 1.2.1}
            bla bla bla

\chapter{Cap 2}
    \section{Sec 2.1}
        bla bla bla
    \section{Sec 2.2}
        \ref{sec:arduino}

\chapter{Cap 3}
    \section{SecThreeDotOne}
        bla bla bla

\chapter*{Outro}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Outro}
    bla bla bla

% PW changes
%\chapter*{Appendix}
%\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Appendix: Arduino}
\appendix
\chapter{Arduino} 
\label{sec:arduino}
    bla bla bla

\end{document}
```

Comment: Ok, thx.
Now it prints on toc: A  Arduino.
It's good (but without that A can looks better)
PS: Now I have two bibliography... I'm confused

Comment: @Gabriele You are not as confused as I am. Which A don't you like? Your MWE has no mention of any bibliography. I suggest you ask another question about that.

Comment: Sorry.
Probably in modifying the code to make the appendix I touched something I shouldn't have and two bibliographies appeared. I'll do another post for this.
Regarding the A, this letter appears to me before the appendix name, both in the ToC and in the title of the chapter.